# unix find command in terminal does not work

Tags: unix, terminal

I need to place a command that will search for all files in the current directory as well as in its sub-directories - ending by ~, and/or all files that start or end by #. The command line will show and erase all files found. Only one command is allowed: no ’;’ or ’&&’ or other shenanigans.

here is my command:

```
find .  -name "#*" -o -name "*#" -o -name "*~"  -print -delete
```

but it erases only the files ending in ~

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes for the name wildcards.  Some shells will do interpolation for you with double quotes, much like perl and php do with strings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. I see the same issue here  (with GNU find 4.4.2). I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You forgot to enclose the conditions in parens `()`. Therefore only the last condition triggered the `-print` and `-delete`. Try `find . \( -name "#*" -o name "*#" -o name "*~" \) -print -delete`.

Comment: @alvits: You should post that as an answer.  (The existing answer diagnoses the problem but doesn't give a solution.)

Comment: @alvits put it as an answer, it worked amazing

Comment: @DomainFlag - I did. I'm happy to have helped.

Comment: That's an interesting answer.  Find on FreeBSD (from AT&T Unix) supports the parens, but they aren't required.  When I commented above I tested first without them and it worked fine, but I don't have a linux to test on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to enclose the conditions with parenthesis `()`. This means that only the last condition will trigger the actions `-print` and `-delete`.

The default is and `-a`, which would not require the parenthesis, that's why most find commands such as `find -type f -name "pattern" -print` works without parenthesis.

You should try:

```
find . \( -name "#*" -o -name "*#" -o -name "*~" \) -print -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

How about  `-print0` primary in conjunction with `xargs -0''` like this .

```
 find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm 

za:temp za$ ls
file.txt    file.txt~
za:temp za$ find . -name "*~" -print0 | xargs -0 rm 
za:temp za$ ls
file.txt
```

Or with `xargs -I {}` plus your comand  which does the same thing .

```
# xargs -I {} to capture the value of find
find . -iname *something* | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

edit : if you can't see the files that start with # using  `find .`  then the  files have spaces within the name of the file(s) like # `file.txt`. you will need to find files with spaces with something like  `find .  -name "* *"` and  then remove the spaces.